# Updating 20 rows in a table is really slow

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I can't figure out why updating only 21 rows in a table takes so much time.

Step 1: I'm creating #tempTable from the StagingTable (it will never have more than 20 rows of data)

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    ID INT NULL,
    UniqueID INT NULL,
    ReportDate VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    DOB Datetime NULL,
    Weight VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    Height VARCHAR(15) NULL)

INSERT INTO #tempTable (
    ID,
    UniqueID,
    ReportDate,
    DOB,
    Weight,
    Height)

SELECT 
    A.ID,
    A.UniqueID,
    A.ReportDate,
    A.DOB,
    A.Weight,
    A.Height
FROM [testDB].[StagingTable] as A
WHERE A.UniqueID = '12345'
```

Step 2. Updating FinalTable:

```
UPDATE [Customers].[FinalTable]
SET ID = B.ID,
    UniqueID = B.UniqueID,
    ReportDate = B.ReportDate,
    DOB = B.DOB,
    Weight = B.Weight,
    Height = B.Height
FROM #tempTable AS B
WHERE [Customers].[FinalTable].[ReportDate] = B.ReportDate
AND [Customers].[FinalTable].[DOB] = B.DOB
```

This query takes more than 30 minutes!
Is there any way to speed up this update process? Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

I just want to add that the FinalTable has millions of rows...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The general form of that type of update is: `UPDATE xx SET <etc> FROM <however many joins, that original table has to be in here>`. You don't have that. I don't know what that means, maybe it's trying to update every row in FinalTable via table scan on the #temp table? Check out the generated query plan, that should tell you something.

Comment: @PhilipKelley The syntax as written actually does work since the fully qualified object name is being used, not an alias, it will use the old style implicit join logic.

Comment: There are a lot of different SQL engines; please specify which one you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only 30 matches, then you want an index on `#temptable(ReportDate, DOB)`:

```
create index idx_temptable_2 on #temptable(ReportDate, DOB);
```

Comment: I think you meant the index to be on FinalTable, aye?

Comment: It worked! Went down from 30 minutes to 2 seconds! Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity. What if I would have let's say 2 millions of matches? Is the indexing also a solution for that?

Comment: @hod Wait... what? Are you saying adding an index on the temp table - which only ever has 20 rows maximum - improved performance from 30 minutes to 2 seconds? As someone who has worked with SQL for 20 years now and thought I understood optimisation pretty well, that baffles me.

Comment: @allmhuran It did! I don't know how that works though, I'm still pretty new to SQL, but I just run it multiple times, and it never took more than 2 seconds.

Comment: I do that all the time and yes, it absolutely works for both small and big tables. I think the idea is mostly that for small tables the index creation causes 'perfect' statistics on the temp-table while for large tables there's the statistics and the actual 'explicit order' of the records. Both result in a better plan. I tend to use clustered ones as the indexing columns often are not the ones you use as values. This way you avoid a look-up in the actual update. In my experience, the overhead of the indexing pretty much always outweighs the gains in UPDATE (or DELETE for that matter) later on.